# What is the best way to compute the transitive import closure of an XML Schema definition?

Tags: validation, xsd

I have a set of XML schema definition resources (files). These files contain mutual import and include directives. For a specific purpose users will instantiate element definitions in a particular XSD. I would like to provide them with an excerpt that contains only the XSD resources required for the task. This means I need to trace all imports and includes to other resources recursively, until I have I set. (A Kleene Star or transitive closure).

I assume that this is implicitly done when I validate the schemata from the entry point. So there might be a call back that lists all dependencies resolved during the process that I can tap into.

The other solution I see is to use DOM and manually parse each schema for the import and include elements. This seems clunky, however.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most convenient way to do this would be with an XSLT stylesheet to which you provide a list of starting points (URIs, or if you need to be careful about chameleon inclusion, namespace-name/URI pairs), and which then fetches the documents and computes the transitive closure, emitting either a list of URIs (or, again, namespace / URI pairs) or a sequence of XSD schema documents.

XQuery could also be used.

And as you suggest, DOM could also be used, with the host programming language of your choice.  (I'd do it in XSLT or XQuery, myself, but that's because I do most of my programming in those languages.)  Some validators may provide an API for getting a list of the schema documents consulted, or you may be able to extract that information from a validator's representation of the PSVI; APIs to XSD validation are not standardized.

Note that in the general case you need to watch out for and handle xsd:redefine and xsd:override, not just xsd:include and xsd:import.

And of course, if this is a one-shot task and the number of modules is likely to be less than fifty, it may be faster to do it by hand than by writing a program to do it automatically.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for the API hooks in the validators. The XSLT solution sounds feasible, but I believe it requires repeated loading of documents, so it may not be very elegant.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  If the program loads the same document repeatedly, its method of calculating the transitive closure of the import/include relation has a leak and won't produce the correct result; but if the program doesn't load each document in the transitive closure at least once, it's going to have the opposite error.  The number of times documents must be loaded is independent of the implementation language.